# A system of linear equations related to the geometry of a finite plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, finite-geometry

Let $\mathcal L$ denote the set of all lines in $\mathbb F_p^2$ parallel to one of the lines
  $$ X:=\{(x,0)\colon x\in\mathbb F_p \},
       \ Y:=\{(0,y)\colon y\in\mathbb F_p \},
       \ Z:=\{(z,z)\colon z\in\mathbb F_p \}. $$
Given a set $S\subseteq\mathbb F_p^2$, with every element $s\in S$ associate a formal variable $x_s$, and consider the system of homogeneous linear equations
  $$ \sum_{s\in S\cap\ell} x_s = 0,\quad \ell\in\mathcal L; $$
thus, there are $|\mathcal L|=3p$ equations and $|S|$ variables. What is the smallest possible size of the set $S$ for which this system has a solution with all variables $x_s$ distinct from $0$, given that $S$ meets every line in $\mathbb F_p^2$? Are there any sets of size $|S|<3p$, meeting every line, for which there are such "nowhere-zero solutions"? If so, can these sets be characterized in a comprehensible way?

Comment: If I've understood correctly, would $S=\{(0,0),(1,0),(2,1),(2,2),(1,2),(0,1)\}$ have the obvious nontrivial solution given by alternating values for the points in the order listed?

Comment: @user44191: Absolutely. I oversimplified the problem trying to make it more appealing. I've made an edit to fix the issue.

Comment: Are the variables $x_s$ interpreted as real variables or could they take values from some finite abelian group?

Comment: Is there a natural way to rephrase this in terms of the finite projective plane?

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz: complex / real /rational / integer - all are equivalent for this problem.

Comment: @user44191: good question; I do not know.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not possible for $p=3$ but I have an example for $p=5.$ It satisfies a stronger condition given at the end which makes sense for any $n \times n$ matrix.

$$\left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 3&1&-1&-1&-2\\ 0&-3&0&
1&2\\ -1&1&0&0&0\\ -1&0&1&0&0
\\ -1&1&0&0&0\end {array} \right] $$

Here the origin is at the top left so the lines parallel to $y=x$ are labelled

$$ [3, -3, 0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0, -1], [-1, 1, 0, -1, 1], [-1, 2, -1, 0, 0], [-2, 0, 1, 1, 0]$$

This was somewhat ad hoc. I'll make a few not especially deep comments and then explain how I got it.

You have a system of $3p$ simultaneous equations in $p^2$ variables. However two are redundant. This means some $p^2-3p+2$ variables can be freely chosen and these uniquely determine the other $3p-2.$ Given such a set of $p^2-3p+2$ free variables (of course there are many) we know that not all of them can be set to $0$ since that will force the all $0$ solution. Setting one of the free variables to $1$ and the rest to $0$ will yield at most $3p-1$ non-zero variables, perhaps less. However the condition that no affine line be **bad** in that it is labelled with all zeros may fail. If so, then setting one or  more free variables to  non-zero values may decrease the number of bad lines and perhaps still keep the number of non-zero variables under $3p.$

I tried this with $p=5.$ The $25$ points are as follows (so the point $(i,j)$ is $a_{5i+j+1}$

$$\left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} a_{{1}}&a_{{2}}&a_{{3}}&a_{{4}}&a_{{5}}
\\  a_{{6}}&a_{{7}}&a_{{8}}&a_{{9}}&a_{{10}}
\\  a_{{11}}&a_{{12}}&a_{{13}}&a_{{14}}&a_{{15}}
\\  a_{{16}}&a_{{17}}&a_{{18}}&a_{{19}}&a_{{20}}
\\  a_{{21}}&a_{{22}}&a_{{23}}&a_{{24}}&a_{{25}}
\end {array} \right]$$

One set of free variables with a candidate assignment is

$a_{{12}}=1,a_{{13}}=a_{{14}}=a_{{15}}=a_{{17}}=a_{{18}}=a_{
{19}}=a_{{20}}=a_{{22}}=a_{{23}}=a_{{24}}=a_{{25}}=0.
$

However that leads to $$
 \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 1&0&0&0&-1\\  0&-1&0&0&
1\\  -1&1&0&0&0\\  0&0&0&0&0
\\  0&0&0&0&0\end {array} \right] .$$

To fix the bottom two horizontal lines I also made $a_{18}=a_{22}=1.$ (Why those? Just a choice of one from each.) That gave the pattern at the top:

$$\left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 3&1&-1&-1&-2\\ 0&-3&0&
1&2\\ -1&1&0&0&0\\ -1&0&1&0&0
\\ -1&1&0&0&0\end {array} \right] $$

---

As nicely noted by @user44191, the fact that the first row has no zero entries means that every non-horizontal line has a non-zero entry. In fact it shows that a seemingly stronger condition is satisfied. I mention it because the fact that $p$ is prime is not essential to the problem. The condition is:

In an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ define a **line** to be any of these $2n+n!$ sets of $n$ entries: a row, a column or $m_{1,\sigma(1)},m_{2,\sigma(2)},\cdots , m_{n,\sigma(n)}$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation.

The goal is to find an $n \times n$ matrix with $3n-1$ or fewer non-zero entries such that

- The sums along each row and column are $0.$
- The sums along the main diagonal and the diagonals "parallel" to it are $0.$
- every line has a non-zero entry.

---

I suspect that a symmetric example is possible for any not too small $n.$

Comment: I have yet to check carefully your construction, but I would not be surprised if there are examples of some general sort ($p>5$).

Comment: As a note, the fact that all other lines contain an element of $S$ is pretty clear. Either they are horizontal or they contain an element of the first line; the first line is entirely nonzero, and none of the horizontal lines are zero.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed pretty clear! There should be an easy proof based on that.